# In what assembly is System.Ext?

Tags: .net-micro-framework

We are building a NETMF project that requires the System.Ext namespace. What assembly contains it?

We have already tried "Add Reference" > ".NET" > look for System.Ext assembly. We have also tried the docs at [MSDN System.Ext Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee433588.aspx) but it doesn't mention the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here - it appears that you need to add a reference to the MFDpwsExtensions.dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd170129.aspx

```
Right-click the References folder in your Visual Studio project.
Choose Add Reference from the context menu
In the Add Reference dialog, choose the .NET tab.
Select MFWsStack.dll in the list, then click OK.
Repeat steps 1 to 3, this time adding MFDpwsExtensions.dll.
If your project is a for a device hosting a service, repeat steps 1 to 3, this time adding MFDpwsDevice.dll.
If your project requires DPWS client functionality, repeat steps 1 to 3, this time adding MFDpwsClient.dll.
```